# Decimals dont show and adds 000

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a string filed in my crystal report with a value of 696 000.00. But I want to be displayed as 6,960,00 in my report. I am using below formula but that's not working. Any ideas?

the Normal value befor I add the formua is 6960.

ToText( ToNumber({Fakturalinje.ItemDescription2}))

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways...

One right click on the field and go to format and select required option.

Second way
ToText({Fakturalinje.ItemDescription2},'#')

Format window will be like this.

[image]

Comment: hi, the frist one i did not find anywhere. I did right click and go to format. r

on the code i do get an error when i try it out. Error: The ) is Missing. dont seem like it works.